# How to remove existing shortcuts for a given key combination in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

How to remove all existing hooks for a given shortcut?

For example on image bellow I want only `Ctrl+Alt+S` to open up `Options` but that key combination is also hooked to other things. I want to disconnect everything else and leave it only for `Options`. How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: Click on `Assign`. This will assign the keystroke to the new command. You don't need to remove it first.

Comment: Did you want to ask something else perhaps? Did you try assigning and found that the original command was still invoked? That's a different question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The problem is that `Assign` adds new keystoke to the list of currently used ones. What I want is to clear the currently used ones and then add new keystroke.

Answer (score -1):

Its because your custom shortcut set as Global and VS will override it when there is exist specificly assignment for that key combination..

All you need to do remove existing binding, to do that;

1. Go to Tools => Options => Environemnt => Keyboard
2. Select your command;
3. Set your shortcut key and click 'Assing'. You will see a selectbox that titled "Shortcut currently used by"
4. Go to that existing binding, select it and click remove

and enjoy your custom binding.

See pic below;
[image]